# random chimes in linux

Tags: linux, audio, gnome

I have no idea how to find any information about this.  I am running redhat 5 with a gnome destkop.  Periodically, I hear chimes, three tones, either ascending or descending, at random intervals.  It used to be once or twice an hour, but has become more frequent.  Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: What apps do you run? Anything in the background or sitting in the notification area? An instant messaging app (Pidgin) for instance?

Comment: do you have a program called TreoHour installed

Comment: @regan it's pidgin.  Thanks.  Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.  I run pidgin in the background for work, but I hardly ever have it foregrounded, so I never associated the notification with the program.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's Pidgin, per my comment. You can change notification settings so it doesn't ding on status changes.